# Infinite series expansion of $\arcsin (x)$ and $\arccos (x)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How to find the infinite series expansion of $\arcsin (x)$ and $\arccos (x)$?

Comment: For $\arcsin x$, use the general binomial theorem to expand $(1-t)^{-1/2}$, and integrate from $0$ to $x$ term by term.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

As $$\frac{d(\arcsin x)}{dx}=(1-x^2)^{-\dfrac12}$$

expand the right hand side & integrate either side

FInally set $x=0\implies \arcsin x=0 $ to find the arbitrary constant

We can use $\arcsin x+\arccos x=\dfrac\pi2$ for $\arccos x$